# Find all the ManyToManyField targets that are not connected to a ManyToManyField haver

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Suppose I have 2 models connected by a many to many relation

```
from django.db import models

class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Batch(models.Model):
    records = models.ManyToManyField(Record)
```

Now I want to find all the Records that are not connected to a Batch.

I would have thought it would be one of

```
Record.objects.filter(batch=[])
#TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got [].
Record.objects.filter(batch__count=0)
Record.objects.filter(batch__len=0)
#FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: count
```

Or something like that. But those don't work. They seem to act like they expect batch to be singular rather then a set.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
Record.objects.filter(batch=None)
```

yes, I was amazed by that as well when I found out.

This works because Django for each relation makes a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so if there is no `batch`, it will join with a `NULL`/`None` record and so we can filter on that one.